# Macro to Skip Blank Lines

Tags: vba

I understand that this is a question that has been asked before in a multitude of forms, but every time I try to use the solution to answer my problem, it's not working and I can't figure out how to adjust to make it work for me.

I have a sheet that, with formulas, pulls all of the data from a daily-updated spreadsheet based on NBA games; in other words, who they're playing, what their opponent's rank is, etc...  This creates a large spreadsheet with a line for each player with the aforementioned data next to players who are active tonight.

If a player isn't active, his line is blank.

I want to set up a way to automatically parse a new sheet with *just* the list of active players, skipping the inactive players.  I understand that I need to create a looped macro that will go through each cell and copy that cell value if it <>"", but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried already to see if the community can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer this myself, sorry I wasn't able to post this sooner.  I had the macro check for an empty cell in Column P, if there wasn't one, I had it copy that row to a sheet specified by that player's position.

```
Sub ActivePlayers()

Dim i As Long

Sheets("AllPlayers").Select
' Find the last row of data
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' Loop through each row
For i = 3 To FinalRow
    ' Decide if to copy based on column P and which sheet to copy to based on Column B
    ThisValue = Cells(i, 16).Value
    Position = Cells(i, 2).Value
    If ThisValue <> "" Then
        Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 33).Copy
        Sheets(Position).Select
        NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("AllPlayers").Select

    End If
Next i

End Sub
```